# I want to encrypt my powershell script using a key

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I don't want to show my code so i want to encrypt the script which is difficult to decrypt.

If possible i want to run my encrypted script through power shell script.

Comment: scripts aren't designed to be obfuscated, if you need to make your code 'private' use a compiled language and an obfuscator, you could always wrap your powershell code within a C# program and run it obfuscated that way.

Comment: The computer running the script obviously has to have access to the unencrypted form. If that's the computer belonging to the person you're trying to hide the script from (and especially if they have admin privileges there) you've got an insurmountable problem. The only way to keep code "safe" is to keep it running on machines that *you* and *only you* have access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use PS2EXE to pack scripts as exe's. here is the link to the code [link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PS2EXE-Convert-PowerShell-9e4e07f1).

The code needs to be updated to account for newer version of powershell. Where the script checks for PSVerion.Major for version 4 change the -eq to -gt.

It can be a little tricky to use at first but the code is solid minus the update listed above.

Comment: Just found this: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PS2EXE-GUI-Convert-e7cb69d5
Looks like somebody picked up maintenance/ improvements of the original code.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is really worth

Comment: Installation
PS C:\> Install-Module ps2exe

Usage
  Invoke-ps2exe .\source.ps1 .\target.exe
or

  ps2exe .\source.ps1 .\target.exe

https://github.com/MScholtes/PS2EXE